# How to solve draw() it does not draw my screen

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make a gaze tracking in android studio. And I am trying to draw on screen a rectangle to the corresponding point of gaze. But my method doesn't work. I don't have any experience in drawing in android studio.
This is my draw class

```
public class drawMargins extends View {
    Paint paint;
    private volatile Margin margin;

public drawMargins(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init(null);
}

    public drawMargins(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(attrs);
    }
    public drawMargins(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(attrs);
    }


    public void updateMargin(Margin margin2) {
        margin = margin2;
        postInvalidate();
    }


private void init(@Nullable AttributeSet set)
{

}

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {

    super.draw(canvas);
    if (margin==null)
        return;
    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);

    canvas.drawRect(
    (float)((canvas.getWidth()/8)*margin.getX()),
    (float)((canvas.getHeight()/8)*margin.getY()),
    (float)((canvas.getWidth()/8)*margin.getX()+canvas.getWidth()/8),
    (float)((canvas.getHeight()/8)*margin.getY()+canvas.getHeight()/8),paint);
    }
}
```

and this is how I find the viewbyid("Draw") and update the vars:

```
DrawMargins = (drawMargins)LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.activity_live_preview,null).findViewById(R.id.Draw);

            Margin eyeNose = new Margin(marginX(),marginY());


        Margin drawOnScreen = onScreen(correspondingOnScreen(eyeNose,NEMargin,SEMargin,SWMargin,NWMargin,0),0,8,0,8,0 );    


    DrawMargins.updateMargin(drawOnScreen);
```

Should I call the draw method? With what canvas?

Comment: Are you sure thatthe view occupies space on screen. By the way, you did a inverse identation here: class names starts with a uppercase letter and variables starts with a lower case letter

Comment: `(canvas.getWidth()/8)*margin.getX()` So, one eighth of the width, times the margin? Seems like instead you would want 1/8th the width **+** the margin? If the margin is any more then (8x8), the rect will currently be drawn outside the bounds of the display.  `(160/8)*8 >= 160`

Comment: Also, you would need to draw the rect to be >= 1px in size, you currently draw `(x, y, x, y)` which has no size. You need to draw, `(x, y, x+1, y+1)`

Comment: Paint myPaint = new Paint();
myPaint.setColor(Color.rgb(0, 0, 0));
myPaint.setStrokeWidth(10);
c.drawRect(100, 100, 200, 200, myPaint);

Comment: Mark ,I am calling (x,y,x+1,y+1). margin.getx() and margin.get(y) get me a value between 1 and 8. i multiply that by canvas height/8 width/8 for x/y and I multiply and add an 8th of canvas for x+1/y+1.  Bhuvaneshwaran Vellingiri I initialised the margin in constructor and it calls draw() only once. it doesn't calls it thereafter

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `invalidate()` instead of `postInvalidate()` in `updateMargins()`. This will call `draw()` and should draw the rectangle.

Comment: I put a log.i in the draw function. It isn't being called

Comment: Is `draw()` being called after you update your `margins` variable? If not, then call `viewbyid("Draw")` after the `super.draw(canvas)` statement. This way, your `margins` get updated before a rectangle should be drawn.

Comment: still the draw method isn't called at all

Comment: Should I also implement onDraw method somehow?

Comment: Yes, try replacing `draw` with `onDraw`.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you do one step at a time. I don't know exactly how you have your Activity or Fragment set, so I am just gonna go through that as well.

To keep things simple, let me assume that there is only Activity and no Fragments. You need two Java Class to get your objective accomplished: `DrawMarginsActivity` and `DrawMargins`.

1. `DrawMargins` is a `Custom View`. Custom views help you create your own custom drawing. Refer this for more details: https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing . You need to override the `onDraw(Canvas canvas)` method. This method has the `canvas` parameter and you will be drawing on to this canvas.
2. Now you need to add `DrawMargins` view to your `DrawMarginsActivity`. You can do this by adding this view to your `DrawMarginsActivity`'s layout file. Then you can get a reference to the `DrawMargins` view via `findViewById()`.
3. Be default, when your Activity is created, the `DrawMargins`'s `onDraw()` method will be called and it will render. But if you want to call the `onDraw()` again, you have to call `DrawMargins.invalidate()` method. This will invalidate the view and call the `onDraw()` method for you.
4. I am not sure on which action you want the view to draw. Based on that, you need to call the `invalidate()` method.